# How to genreate a sts claim with default values for development and testing

Tags: asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity

We a have asp.net webform application where we use STS claims to manage user authorization. The workflow is pretty straight forward. User hits a login page enters credentials, a claim is generated which contains their rights. This claim is used to pass rights to our applications WCF service to control what data they have access to etc. For automated testing (and even development) I would like to setup a mechanism where the automated test bypasses the login and a dummy claim with the appropriate criterion is is used on page load.  I would like to accomplish this without re-writing the existing sts service. Does anyone know if it is possible to create a dummy claim and when the main site is call inject this into document. I feel comfortable with working around the authentication (isAuthenticated) but I'm not sure about the claim for authorization. I'd appreciate any suggestions or hints on where to look/read up on creating a development/stub claim.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the best place for injection in your code is, but you can always create ClaimsIdentity/ClaimsPrincipal yourself with any claims you want.